# Is DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT just needed when in the same machine?

Tags: oracle, rman, dataguard

I am a little confuse. I have created a primary database with DG names `+DADOS` AND `+DGARC`, and the standby (in another server) with DG names `+DATA` and `+FRA`. I don't have configured the `DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT` and `LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT` yet, but it's working fine.

For example, I have created a datafile in the primary,  the file is:

```
+DADOS/jupiter/datafile/manu.283.1077576101
```

and it comes converted in the standby.

```
Media Recovery Log +FRA/jupiterstb/archivelog/2021_07_10/thread_2_seq_327.261.1077575237
    Media Recovery Log +FRA/jupiterstb/archivelog/2021_07_10/thread_2_seq_328.294.1077576145
    Successfully added datafile 6 to media recovery
    Datafile #6: '+DATA/jupiterstb/datafile/manu.277.1077576447'
    Media Recovery Waiting for thread 2 sequence 329 (in transit)
```

`DB_FILE_NAME_CONVERT` AND `LOG_FILE_NAME_CONVERT` just needed to be configured when duplicating in the same machine?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters are also used when you have a different file system between two databases which need different paths to the files. Eg if you used ASM for your primary but a “regular” file system on your standby, or Windows drives on your primary and unix mounts on your secondary.

Answer (score 1):

Your primary and standby databases use Oracle Managed Files. With the `db_create_file_dest` (and `db_create_online_log_dest_N`) set to the diskgroup name, and with an FRA, the files are named automatically without the need for any CONVERT parameter. That is the typical way to go with ASM. This is not related to duplicating on the same or a separate machine.

Comment: But if i was using the filesystem and OMF, would the behavior be the same?